# booting into 12.04 results in a purple sceen for just a second.

Tags: boot, plymouth, i915

I have a vanilla Ubuntu install running on an Ivy-Bridge ultrabook that is using Intel 4000 graphics. I have enabled autologin via a line in the lightdm config file. My boot is very fast, however, it is ugly. The screen will be black, all solid purple for a second, then Plymouth for a second, then desktop.

I would really like to figure out what the solid purple is and how to remove it. I would like to either have a different color (black) or skipped entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit like a "nomodeset" problem. But I am not 100% sure ....

I once had this problem that my display during boot was black and came only back for login. Then I set the "nomodeset" option as a boot parameter.

You could try that by setting this option and check if it helps. If not you remove this option again.

More here:

[Nomodeset Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)